# Expected value of Hamiltonian with operators in atomic units

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hamiltonian, born-oppenheimer-approximation

Hello I am currently working on a problem sheet for university, and am confused on how to solve it correctly.

We deal with a helium atom and are asked to express the Hamiltonian in atomic units. This is easy as we can use the Born-Oppenheimer approximation:

**H=(-1/2)∇₁²-(1/2)∇₂²-(2/r₁)-(2/r₂)+(1/r₁₂)**

Now, the wave function of the electrons is seperated into a product of two 1s-functions:

[image]

This is understable until this point. Now it is asked to formulate the expected value for the wave function, using these expressions given here:[image]

But I don't really know how to approach this: As the function is expressed as a product of two 1s-function, I don't think we can seperate the integral and formulate it like this. I have tried to write that down, but my problem is how we can deal with the fact that the expressions only deal with single functions. Here is what I tried: I don't know how to incorporate the expressions.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, actually, doable. You are on the right path, but your expectation value definition is not correct. Since you have 6 spatial dimensions (3 for each particle), it should be:

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2) | A | \psi (\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2) \rangle 
&= \int \int \psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2)^* A \big(\psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2)\big)\mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_1 \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_2 \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2)^* A \big(\psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2)\big)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}y_1\mathrm{d}z_1\mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}y_2\mathrm{d}z_2
\end{align}
$$

Let's look at the first term, $\langle \psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2) | -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 | \psi (\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2) \rangle$. This is:

$$
\left\langle \psi(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2) \middle| -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 \middle| \psi (\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2) \right\rangle
= \int\int \phi(\vec{r}_1)^* \phi(\vec{r}_2)^* \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 \bigg)\bigg(\phi(\vec{r}_1) \phi(\vec{r}_2)\bigg) \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_1 \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_2$$
Notice that the operator does not act on $\phi(\vec{r}_2)$, so we can rewrite it as:

$$
\int\int \phi(\vec{r}_1)^* \phi(\vec{r}_2) \phi(\vec{r}_2)^* \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 \bigg)\bigg(\phi(\vec{r}_1) \bigg) \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_1 \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_2$$
We can also reorder the integrals:
$$
\int\int \phi(\vec{r}_1)^* \phi(\vec{r}_2) \phi(\vec{r}_2)^* \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 \bigg)\bigg(\phi(\vec{r}_1) \bigg) \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_2 \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_1$$
And since $\vec{r}_1$ is constant with respect to $\vec{r}_2$, we can pull out the appropriate terms:
$$
\int\phi(\vec{r}_1)^*\bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 \bigg)\bigg(\phi(\vec{r}_1) \bigg) \int \phi(\vec{r}_2) \phi(\vec{r}_2)^*  \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_2 \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_1$$
But now we can do the integral for the variable $\vec{r}_2$! Why? Because it's just the norm of the one-particle wave function, which is $s_2$ in our case. So we are left with:
$$
s_2 \int\phi(\vec{r}_1)^*\bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \Delta_1 \bigg)\bigg(\phi(\vec{r}_1) \bigg) \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}_1$$
Can you see what is this quantity?

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I figured that the psi(r2) term would cancel, but could not explain why but now it makes much more sense. The psi(r2) is not affected by the hamiltonian at all if we look at an operator that only works on r1.

Comment: @冰淇淋 exactly! You can also use bra-ket notation for the calculation. Your ket will be just $| \phi(r_1)\rangle |\phi(r_2) \rangle$. And if you calculate the expectation of, let's say, $\Delta_1$, it will only effect $| \phi(r_1)\rangle$, and $| \phi(r_2)\rangle$ will be "eliminated" by it's bra "partner". All in all, it's expectation will be $ \langle \psi(r_1) |\Delta_1 | \phi(r_1)\rangle$ (you can add the $-1/2$ prefactor easily). A similar thing will happen with each of the other terms.

Comment: Would the answer for the question simply be T1+T2+V1+V2+V12 then?

Comment: @冰淇淋 Sorry, I mislead you a little bit. The one-particle wave functions' norm is not $1$ but $s_i$, so their contribution should be $s_i$. This means that the first term is $T_1 s_2$ and the whole expression is $T_1 s_2 + T_2 s_1 + V_1 s_2 + V_2 s_1 + V_{12}$.

Comment: Makes sense! On my sheet, s1=s2=1 so it’s the same either way :D thanks for the help